# Why HDInsight cluster can use a storage account in another resource group?

Tags: azure-hdinsight

I'm creating one HDInsight cluster in resource group1, but when choosing the storage, it turns out that I can use a storage account in another resource group.

But as far as I know, all resources (including HDInsight) should be bound to only one resource group.

So how is that the HDInight cluster could reach a storage account that is not the same as itself?

Comment: `But as far as I know, all resources (including HDInsight) should be bound to only one resource group` - That's not true. Each resource must belong to just one resource group only but they can certainly use resources from other resource groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is a false statement - But as far as I know, all resources (including HDInsight) should be bound to only one resource group.

When you using Azure HDInsight - You can use Storage account which can be different Resource Group.

Note: The Azure HDInsight cluster is in the same location as the default storage.

[image]